# Want Tick mark and X-mark using current date and current time using Excel formula

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I have 4 task everyday, 2 task to be completed before 10 AM and next 2 task to be completed before 5:30 PM. need to use current day and current time. so if today current time cross the 10 AM i want "tick" mark symbol if not "X" mark symbol to be displayed it has to go on for a week.

so if my excel is always in open it should be updated as per above condition.

is it possible by using excel formula...

[image: output result to be like in this image]

Comment: It is yes. Subtract the desired time from the current time. If the result is greater than 0 time has passed. Look at using `TIME()` and `NOW()` and wrapping the whole thing in a simple `IF()`. If you get stuck @ my name and i'll take a look at what you have done.

Comment: So how to get  tick mark for pervious days...

Comment: Oh a similar comparison , if you can;t just compare directly with `IF(A3<TODAY(),✓,X)` then you can drill down further using DATE() for comparison, for example today would be `DATE(YEAR(TODAY()),MONTH(TODAY()),DAY(TODAY()))` but you can subtract day's months or years individually in the relative field.

Comment: i used this formula =IF($A5=TODAY()+1,"",IF($A5=TODAY()-1,$G$1,IF($A5=TODAY(),IF(TIMEVALUE($J$5)>TIMEVALUE("17:30:00"),$G$1,$H$1),"")))   but i get the answer for yesterday and today only. not for other previous days

Comment: In J5 i use current time formula..

Comment: Rather than using `=Today()-1` you can just use less than (`<Today()`) or greater than (`>Today()`) and you should then get what you were after...

Answer (score 0):

I use a check mark to show a completed task also, but add a time stamp several columns over. I've modified my script to fit your situation by clicking in a cell in Column B or C, it puts an "a" in the cell using a Marlett font, which makes a **check mark** if before 10 am, otherwise an "r" which makes an **X**.

Perhaps this can be modified for you situation, by adding another section for the 17:30 time. I prefer using VBA rather than a formula, as it's "dynamic" on cell changes (just clicking in the cell). Clicking out and back in the same cell again removes the check mark or X.

```
Private Sub Worksheet_SelectionChange(ByVal Target As Range)

 'Mark Task completed if finished before 10 am

  If Target.Cells.Count > 1 Then Exit Sub

    'Only looking at column B & C, rows 3 thru 31
    If Not Intersect(Target, Range("B3:C31")) Is Nothing Then

        Target.Font.Name = "Marlett"

            If Target = vbNullString Then
               If Time() < "10:00:00" Then
                   Target = "a"
                Else
                   Target = "r
                End If 
            Else

                Target = vbNullString


            End If
      End If
End Sub`
```

Hope this helps if you haven't found a viable solution yet.